# How to make administrator and other normal users access different GUI in Java to MySQL connection when they press the same login button?

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I am creating a daily attendance system for employees using Java and Mysql as the DBMS.Firstly the application shows login form by which each employee is going to fill his/her username and password.If she does not have,she is going to register then she will get the access.So what i need during registration for the one who registered as the administrator to have different GUI after login compared to the GUI faced by other users.You can see the code below what i can add to the login button

```
  private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      


    String username=tx.getText();
    String password=tx2.getText();

    if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || (username.equals("") && password.equals("")))
    {
        login.setEnabled(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html><font size=5 color=blue>PLEASE ENTER BOTH USERNAME AND PASSWORD</font></html>");
        login.setEnabled(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }



    else
    {
        String sql= "select * from empdetails where EmpId=? and Password=?";

        try
        {
        st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1,tx.getText());
        st.setString(2,md5(tx2.getText()));     

        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
         {     
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html><font size=5 color=blue>SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN.</font></html>");
        dispose();
        }


        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html><font size=5 color=blue>INVALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD.</font><html>");
        }

    }

         catch(SQLException e)
         {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR TO DATABASE VALUES RETRIEVAL");
         }

   }



}
```

Also can I get help in administrator GUI she can click a button and get the stored values in mysql through the print view and other button show to save them in PDF format.And in what way i can have the system time shown during login of each employee in the company.

Answer (score 0):

Use Role_ID for users and Administrators in your Database. While checking your login, fetch the Role_ID and if it is an administrator, you can show the interface which designed for Admins else proceed to default interface.

To show in Print view and PDF there are third party libraries available. you can use iText http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html for generating your PDF documents. But you have to read the documentation and work flow of the library.

Note: Avoid searching every user name and matching with your credentials. Just query the database whether the provided username and password pair is available as this will speedup te execution.